# Software to move graphics over another. i.e. a bus over a map

Tags: software-recommendation, software

I want to portray the tour of a group of students from the Uni to an exterior site and back.
The idea ist to have a map (static or scrolling) and move a picture of a bus on it.
The look is supposed to resemble a cut out bus being moved of a paper-map.

I am looking for a suitable (free) software to do this.
I am also open for other suggestions to achive that effect.

Comment: Any video editing package is likely to be able to do this, or you could even manually do it in paint and then stitch the images together.

Answer (score 1):

You could try stop-motion. Basically your taking a pic of the bus everytime you move it on the map, then putting it together as a sequence in your editing program. Bout the only free way I can think of

Answer (score 1):

I see that you have some Java experience from your profile. You could use Processing, a Java framework used to teach artists and designers programming and geared toward creating animation, video, graphics, and the like. There are many examples on the site that demonstrate basic animation, displaying images, etc. [processing.org](http://processing.org)